# Issue with fuel injection pump?

Tags: electrical, fuel-injection, fuel-pump

I had been driving a TATA Indica Vista quadrajet 1.3L turbocharged (diesel) yesterday over a total distance of around 250kms. We had like a few stops in between at 5 or 6 places. After stopping it briefly for around 2 mins at around 50 km of continuous driving, the car wasn't starting. When you put the key in ignition all the lights in dashboard speedometer lights up as usual without any issue. Also I wasn't able to hear the "wheezz" sound that i usually hear every time I put the key to ignition (It could also be because of the loud ambient noise on the roads). When I tried to start the vehicle ,the starter motor was cranking the engine as normal but the engine wasn't starting. Tried to start like 5 times and ran the starter motor for about 5sec each time.

I have no prior experience in repairing (haven't tried to repair any parts on my bike or car). But I guess its some problem related to the fuel pump or fuel injectors.

Car was towed to a nearby workshop and since it was late night they didn't do any repair or diagnosis on it. The next day when mechanic started the car, it was starting and running fine without any issue. They even kept it running for an hour on idle and didn't see any issue.

So what possibly could be the issue? Which part should I check? Also what is the sound that I hear when I put the key to ignition? Is it the sound of fuel pump priming?

Comment: The sound will most likely be the fuel pump.

Answer (score 0):

Diesel engines are different from gasoline engines. Spark plugs aren't used in diesel engines. Higher compression ignites diesel fuel but can be difficult to start and run in cooler temperatures. The coil symbol is most likely the glow plug(s) and automatically turns on by the computer relative to outside and coolant temperatures. The glow plug is an actual red hot element powered by the battery to help ignite diesel fuel when temperatures go below a certain temperature. If the glow plug(s) are damaged or worn, starting in cooler temperatures may be difficult as diesel fuel is harder to ignite in cold weather. Once the engine starts up with or without glow plugs, the warmup time takes a little longer in cold weather. Whether the fuel pump runs when ignition is turned on depends on how your diesel engine operates. If you have your owner's manual, read it for information.

Comment: I had driven around 50km continuously till the car showed issues at the last stop. Also in the place where I live the average temperatures are well above 30 degree Celsius. Low temperatures wouldn't be the issue in this case. It seems like some issues with fuel pump as I couldn't hear fuel pump priming in the ignition. Although I have no idea what could cause a sudden issue with fuel pump after running long distances. Probably some issue with electrical connections or something with fuel pump itself. I will edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: Did you have the owner's manual or not for information?

Comment: Nope i do not, it was a second hand car. I didn't get it when we bought it.

Comment: Well, since the repair shop didn't find anything wrong with starting up and idling for an hour, you may have to consider some options. Leave well enough alone if you're not able to determine what occurred, search for diy help on TATA diesel engines or seek help from the repair shop.